# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" when trying to produce a pandas pairplot

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am currently having a problem producing a pandas pairplot for a linear regression model.

I have obtained the data I require and following some cleansing and encoding I am trying to produce pair plots.

Currently I cannot resolve the error I am seeing:

**Code**

```py
our_columns = ["PLACE_CP6","RESULT_NOK"]
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(
          df_dummied[our_columns] ## Our dataframe with list of columns
        , figsize=(10,10) ## Figure size - changes the size of the graph. Smaller number, smaller graph
        , hist_kwds = {'bins': 10}
        , alpha = 1  ## Settings for the keywords
        , diagonal='hist'
        )

plt.show()
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-5c2cce38063e> in <module>
      2 our_columns = ["PLACE_CP6","RESULT_NOK"]
      3 pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(
----> 4           df_dummied[our_columns] ## Our dataframe with list of columns
      5         , figsize=(10,10) ## Figure size - changes the size of the graph. Smaller number, smaller graph
      6         , hist_kwds = {'bins': 10}

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: It would help to see how `df_dummied` was created. In the meantime I suspect what you are looking for is `df_dummied[columns=our_columns]`. See [Indexing/Selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have tried again this morning and it all works fine. I guess this must be and issue with Jupyter Notebook. I did reset the kernel several times yesterday which did not work. After closing Jupyter off and restarting this now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After closing Jupyter off and restarting this now works fine.